# Trying to access a nested class in a method (both are in same class) .

Tags: c#

I was able to access `show()` method in another class

```
class program
{
    int num;
    string name;
    void store()
    {
        num = 1;
        name = "pc";
    }

    private class heai
    {
        public void show()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("hai");
        }
    }

    void display()
    {
        store();
        Console.WriteLine(num + name);
        //how to access show() here ??
    }
}
```

Comment: dont put red flag to question please if you think it deserve red flag please let me know how to ask good questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have an instance from `heai` to access `show`.

Like this:

```
void display()
{
    var h = new heai();
    store();
    Console.WriteLine(num + name);
    h.show(); // here you are calling show on the instance of heai
}
```

By the way: this has nothing to do with nested classes. It would be the same for any other class.

In case you don't want to have an instance of `heai`, you could make `show` `static`:

```
private class heai
{
    public static void show()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("hai");
    }
}
```

And then call it like this:

```
void display()
{
    store();
    Console.WriteLine(num + name);
    heai.show(); // note: we are not accessing an instance of heai here, but the class itself
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the access modifier of the class to public or protected.